# Is it possible to develop an application to run without having a DBMS/RDBMS in back-end?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have some background in ASP.NET applications, and I am also using Webforms, MVC and WinForms.

But right now I need to develop a **WinForms Desktop application in .NET** to run only to the computer which is currently installed not on a shared environment.

It needs to have and support all create, read, edit, delete functions, but **without a database** like SQL or any other RDBMS/DBMS, since I want to avoid having to install it separately.

The application should **store user information** in other **types of files like XML** or something like that.

I want to ask weather if there is a way or not. Which best practice technology should I need to follow?

Comment: Unclear, is the question can the database be on an other Computer/Server , than the running program ? The answer is yes.

Comment: i have edited the question. please dont devote it because in future it would not allow me to ask more questions. you could easily asked in comment for more clearness. thx

Comment: @johni: The downvotes are not just because it is unclear, it is because it is not suitable for Stack Overflow. The question is too broad, it would require too much information to be able to provide a good answer. I am talking like a "5 part tutorial" kind of length

Comment: " but without database like SQL or any other RDBMS/DBMS where i need to install it with application separately"   - you can use `SQLite`

Comment: so how could i solve this problem ? i need to know only that asp.net has this support or not if has what technology is required. i dont think if this would be too broad. :(

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but it's also possible to use a standalone database such as SQLite. Of course, there are other possibilities such as using json/xml serialization to store data, but that would probably be harder and have worst performance.

Comment: why this question tagged asp.net?

Comment: The application should store `user information` or `userS information`?
If it store information for a single user (e.g application owner) or you need to store few records (not many) you can write needed information in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes it is Possible to have data store to be used with Windows Form
>   Applications.

You have multiple options here.

1. [Sql server compact edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=17876)
2. Microsoft Access
3. [Sql Lite](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

Though you have to install SSCE,SqlLite separately in user PC.

But Microsoft Access comes in package with Microsoft office.